# How to narrow indexed access types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a type `Queries` which holds a `query type`, `args type` and `result type`

```js
type Queries = {
 query1 : { args: { id: number   }, return: number }
 query2 : { args: { type: string }, return: string }
 query3 : { args: { world:"hello"}, return: "world"} 
 
}
```

which I use to provide types to a function

```js
type QueryTypes = keyof Queries
function query<T extends QueryTypes>(type:T, args: Queries[T]["args"]){
  return something as Queries[T]["return"]
}

const result1 = query("query1", { id: 0 }) //result1: number
const result2 = query("query1", { type: "hi" }) //result2: string
const result3 = query("query1", { world: "hello" }) //result1: "world"
```

I have trouble narrowing what `args: Queries[T]["args"]` in the function implementation

```js
switch(type){
  case "query1": 
  // args: { id:number } | { type:string } | { world: "hello" }
}
```

is it possible that `Queries[T]["args"]` be narrowed ? like this

```js
switch(type){
  case "query1": 
  // args: { id:number } 
  
 case "query2" :
  // args: { type:string }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think TypeScript generally does not narrow down generic types the way you would need it here. An alternative solution would be to create an object where each key contains a function where `arg` has the corresponding type to the key.

```
function query<T extends QueryTypes>(type:T, args: Queries[T]["args"]){

  const ret: { 
    [K in QueryTypes]: (args: Queries[K]["args"]) => Queries[K]["return"] 
  } = {
    query1: (args) => {
      //     ^? args: { id: number; }

      return 0
    },
    query2: (args) => {
      return ""
    },
    query3: (args) => {
      return "world"
    },
  }

  return ret[type](args)
}
```

That is probably the only idiomatic way without relying on many type assertions.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#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-m4y7cdqgrqgA)